# Linking data from a MS Access Table to a different table based on form input

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am not new to programming but I am new to MS Access. I have a new database that tracks parts loan to other organizations. One table (call it table A) has a form that enters the loan info (part number, name, date POC, balance to be paid back etc). The second table (table B) and form keeps track of parts paybacks. I have two questions:

1. When filling out form B the person enters the part number being paid back. How do I pull the part name from table A and fill the part name field (both in the table and on the form) with the appropriate name? I want to maintain continuity.
2. Table A tracks payback status as well. It has a field that takes in a payback quantity and calculates the balance and if it is 0, closes the loan. How do I take the payback quantity entered in form B and enter against a part number in form A so the balance can be calculated?

Comment: 1. Don't save part name in table B, only table A record ID. Have table B in a subform linked to table A form. Record ID will automatically save to table B record. 2. Usually aggregate data should not be saved, calculate it from raw data transaction records when needed.

Comment: @June7  re q1: that's Greek but now I know where to look. Re q2: never knew that. What mechanism would I use to do that when generating a report?

Comment: 1. involves dependent related tables in a form/subform arrangement - basic functionality. 2. Maybe this will help http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html